# Unity, movement of a sheet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm not sure how to ask the question to be clear, I'll explain my problem. I apologize in advance if the question may be unclear or perhaps even banal, I'm still learning the world of Unity.

I want to create a sheet (in this case with a 12-sided shape) where, by raising one of the edges of the sheet, the others follow the raised edge but in any case other edges remain attached. I tried to carry out some tests, the first immediately abandoned which used a simple mesh (modelled on blender) where through "**MeshFilter**" I tried to deform the sheet, but without having been successful.
The second attempt was to model the sheet with the usual 12-sided shape, but dividing each single face of the shape, subsequently with unity I applied "**Configurable joints**" to connect one edge of the sheet to its previous and subsequent edge . This way, I can make the flaps follow but I don't get what I want. How can I develop this thing? What is the best method (that is not too heavy for a smartphone's memory) to be able to make the flaps linked to each other?

I hope the question was clear enough, if it wasn't, I will try to specify even better what I have in mind and what the objective would be. I also attach a screenshot of the shape of the sheet (Some sides are invisible as I did not model the internal faces, as it is a test mesh)

Thanks everyone for the help :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a `cloth` component that I think might help you

- Documenation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cloth.html
- Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nc_ZMgEFj-A

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).